# Angular2 static HTTP client

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular2-http

I want to use static HTTP client service for some reasons. I tried it like the following but I got an error. Is creating static the service possible?

static service:

```
import { Http, URLSearchParams, Headers }  from '@angular/http';

export class ExampleService {
    static postSendTransaction(data, callback) {
        Http.post('https://xxxxxxxx', JSON.stringify(data), { // I got error here
            headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
        }).subscribe(
            response => {
                callback({data: response.json(), error: null});
            },
            error => {
                callback({data: null, error: error.statusText});
            }
        );
    }
}
```

example call:

```
ExampleService.postSendTransaction(this.data, postSendTransactionCallback);
```

I got this error:

> Property 'post' does not exist on type 'typeof Http'.

Comment: are you sure you injected your service in the constructor?

Comment: Put simply, the Angular `Http` class is not designed to be used as a static object.  You need to inject it into the constructor and use it the way it was designed.

Comment: You likely have XY problem, which means that the question should be modified to reflect the thing you're trying to do instead of the way you're trying to achieve it (which is wrong).